# Какой дистрибутив Linux выбрать для размещения проекта на netcore

Tags: asp.net-core

Какой дистрибутив Linux выбрать, для изучения и развертывания  приложения на netcore.

Comment: Любой, в котором поддерживается Net Core. [Ubuntu Server](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) для начала более чем сойдет.

Comment: @ГеннадийП Спасибо за ответ, просто  как раз их много и они разные

Comment: Собственно, на сайте есть [таблица совместимости](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите на сайте microsoft список доступных платформ: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x и выберите наиболее подходящую для себя.

Вообще говоря, выбор дистрибутива Linux обоснованно считается холиварной темой, из более-менее объективных советов в доинтернетовскую эпоху в фидо советовали "ставьте такой же дистрибутив, как у ближайшего вашего знакомого Linux-гуру". Если есть живой знакомый - рекомендация до сих пор жива ) Если нет - выбирайте любой.

В принципе, очень широко пользуются на домашних системах ubunty с клонами и debian, а в корпоративном сегменте чаще любят centos (за счёт поддержки и умеренно-консервативного подхода к обновлениям).

Могу для начала рекомендовать вот такую статью: https://habr.com/post/332920/ - я по ней разворачивал под centos7 и различий особо нет с описанным.